# Работа с DOM в jQuery

Tags: jquery

Данная корзина при нажатии на кнопки ADD TO CART может: 1)добавлять количество товаров в ITEM, сумму товаров в $, а также динамически добавлять DOM элементы в скрытую часть корзины(`li` кладутся внутрь `ul`, внутрь `li` также кладется элементы с информацией о товаре).

Код данной корзины позволяет производить некоторые манипуляции с DOM(удалять целиком все товары из скрытой корзины, удалять товары по отдельности и т.д.).Единственная проблема в том, что при выполнении `$(this).closest('.newLi').find('.spanDollar').html();` 
`$('#price').html((+price - +minusDollar).toFixed(2));` от общей суммы отнимается цена всех товаров сразу, а не какого-то отдельного.

Как можно решить проблему?

*HTML*

```
<div id="arrow">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
</div>
<div id="container1">
    <div id="cart-menu">
        <span id="yc">Your cart</span>
    </div>
    <div id="counts">
        <span id="counter" class="visible-span">0</span>
        <span class="visible-span">ITEMS</span>
        <span class="visible-span">|</span>
        <span class="visible-span">$</span>
        <span id="price" class="visible-span">0</span>
    </div>
    <ul id="ul"></ul>
</div>

<div id="container2">
    <div class="stuff">
        <img src="images/man1.jpg">
        <p>$<span class="dollar">44.85</span></p>
        <p class="title">JACKET</p>
        <input type="button" value="ADD TO CART" class="btn"  />
    </div>
    <div class="stuff">
        <img src="images/man2.jpg">
        <p>$<span class="dollar">62.95</span></p>
        <p class="title">JEANS</p>
        <input type="button" value="ADD TO CART" class="btn" />
    </div>
    <div class="stuff">
        <img src="images/man3.jpg">
        <p>$<span class="dollar">75.00</span></p>
        <p class="title">T-SHIRT</p>
        <input type="button" value="ADD TO CART" class="btn" />
    </div>
    <div class="stuff">
        <img src="images/man5.jpg">
        <p>$<span class="dollar">25.00</span></p>
        <p class="title">GLASSES</p>
        <input type="button" value="ADD TO CART" class="btn" />
    </div>
</div>
```

*jQuery*

```
$(function (){
  $('.btn').click(function (){
    //arrow at the bottom should be animated every time you press the button
    $(function(){
        $('#arrow').animate(
            {
                bottom: '300px',
                fontSize: '60px',
                opacity: '0'
            }, 2000,(function(){
                $('#arrow')
                    .css('opacity', '1')
                    .css('bottom', '0')
                    .css('fontSize', '0')
            }));
    });

    //+1 to ITEMS every time you press the button
    var counter = $('#counter').html();
    counter++;
    $('#counter').html(counter);

    //add price to the cart
    var dollar = $(this).closest('.stuff').find('.dollar').html();
    var title = $(this).closest('.stuff').find('.title').html();
    var price = $('#price').html();
    $('#price').html((+price + +dollar).toFixed(2));

    //+1 li element to the hidden cart at the top of the site

    var bool = false;

    //creating new elements, that should be contain stuff info *WRITTEN IN JavaScript*
    var ul = document.getElementById('ul');
    var newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.setAttribute('class', 'newLi');
    var spanPrice = document.createElement('span');
    spanPrice.setAttribute('class', 'spanPrice');
    spanPrice.innerHTML = 'Price:';
    var spanDollar = document.createElement('span');
    spanDollar.setAttribute('class', 'spanDollar');
    spanDollar.innerHTML = dollar;
    var spanStuff = document.createElement('span');
    spanStuff.setAttribute('class', 'spanStuff');
    spanStuff.innerHTML = 'Stuff:';
    var spanTitle = document.createElement('span');
    spanTitle.setAttribute('class', 'spanTitle');
    spanTitle.innerHTML = title;
    var del = document.createElement('a');
    del.setAttribute('class', 'del');
    del.setAttribute('href', '#');
    del.innerHTML = 'X';
    var yourCart = document.getElementById('yc');
    yourCart.innerHTML = '';
    var ycLink = document.createElement('a');
    ycLink.setAttribute('id', 'ycLink');
    ycLink.setAttribute('href', '#');
    ycLink.innerHTML = 'Your cart';
    var firstLi = document.createElement('li');
    firstLi.setAttribute('id', 'firstLi');
    var removeCart = document.createElement('input');
    removeCart.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    removeCart.setAttribute('value', 'REMOVE CART');
    removeCart.setAttribute('id', 'removeCart');

    //add elements to the hidden cart *WRITTEN IN JavaScript*
    ul.appendChild(newLi);
    newLi.appendChild(spanPrice);
    newLi.appendChild(spanDollar);
    newLi.appendChild(spanStuff);
    newLi.appendChild(spanTitle);
    newLi.appendChild(del);
    yourCart.appendChild(ycLink);
    firstLi.appendChild(removeCart);

    // open/close hidden cart
    $('#ycLink').click(function(){
       if(!bool){
           bool = true;
           ul.insertBefore(firstLi, ul.firstChild);
           //option to remove all cart elements
           $('#removeCart').click(function (){
               $('li').remove();
               $('#ycLink').remove();
               $('#price').html('0');
               $('#counter').html('0');
               $('#yc').html('Your cart');
               $('#ul').css('display', 'none');
               bool = false;
           });
           $('#ul').slideDown('slow');
       }
        else{
           bool = false;
           $('#ul').slideUp('slow');
           $('#firstLi').remove();
       }
    });

    //remove selected elements
    $('.del').click(function (){
        $(this).parent().remove();
        counter--;
        $('#counter').html(counter);
        var minusDollar = $(this).closest('.newLi').find('.spanDollar').html();
        $('#price').html((+price - +minusDollar).toFixed(2));
        if(ul.lastChild === firstLi){
            $('#firstLi').remove();
            $('#ycLink').remove();
            $('#price').html('0');
            $('#yc').html('Your cart');
            $('#ul').css('display', 'none');
            bool = false;
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вы уже используете jQuery. Создание новых элементов надо переписать. Например:

   ```
   var ul = $('#ul');
   var newLi = $('<li class="newLi"></li>')
   var spanPrice = $('<span class="spanPrice">Price:</span>');
   newLi.append(spanPrice);
   ...
   ul.append(newLi);
   ```

   Код станет в несколько раз короче и прозрачнее.
2. Один и тот же `id="ycLink"` присваивается многим элементам. Это, во-первых, нарушение спецификации html, а во-вторых, мина, заложенная под селектор `$('#ycLink')`, который не будет делать то, что Вы думаете он будет делать.
3. Каждый раз, когда срабатывает `$('.btn').click`, Вы вызываете `$('.del').click(function(){...});`. Этот код каждый раз добавляет всем `$('.del')` элементам новый `click` обработчик.  Следует использовать `$('body').on('click', '.del', function(){...})` в `$(document).ready`.

Удачи.

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Вы извините, но приведённом коде какой-то ад.

Почему у вас все обработчики назначаются внутри `$('.btn').click(function (){` ? Таким образом, у вас каждый раз при добавлении в корзину добавляется обработчик удаления(т.е. у вас при одном нажатии на крестик будет много раз выполняться один и тот же обработчик). Обработчики нужно вынести за пределы `$('.btn').click(function (){` и использовать делегат. Или же назначать обработчик конкретно добавленному элементу, а не всем по классу.

Внутри `$('.del').click(function (){` вы используете переменную `counter` следующим образом:

```
counter--;
$('#counter').html(counter);
```

Я подозреваю что вы хотели еще сперва дописать его получение, потому что сейчас непонятно от чего оно вычитается:

```
var counter = $('#counter').html();
```

Опять же, при удалении, у вас `$(this).parent().remove();` вызывается первой строчкой! Т.е. вы сперва удаляете элемент целиком, а потом пытаетесь ниже получить какие-то его свойства(Например, minusDollar). Но это же невозможно, он уже удален!

В общем, для начала мне кажется нужно разобраться что вы хотите сделать и изучить подробнее механизмы событий и работы с *DOM* в *jQuery*.